# How to set function in HTML while outputing HTML with PHP

Tags: pdf, php, mysql

Sorry for little weird tittle, english is not my native language, and its little hard for me to express myself about this, so I hope i'll get clearer in explanation :)

I have this piece of code, to fetch all rows from MYSQL db, and when it fetch it out, i want to do some action on everyone of that row. (I want to display different PDF files stored in DB).

Take a look

```
include_once 'dbcon.php';
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT email, name FROM upload_jezici  ");


while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['email']. " " . $row['name'] . "<input type='button' name='' value= 'button' > <br />";

}
```

How to increment title of button name, on every row, so I can use it later to access it via POST method to display PDF?
I want something like this...
1st row : name='button1'
2nd row : name ='button2' etc etc..
When im outputing HTML with PHP it only allow me to read some variables, not some functions stored in quotation marks.

Please help guys! Thanks

Comment: **WARNING**: `mysql_query` is an obsolete interface and should not be used in new applications as it's being removed in future versions of PHP. A modern replacement like [PDO is not hard to learn](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/why-you-should-be-using-phps-pdo-for-database-access/). If you're new to PHP, a guide like [PHP The Right Way](http://www.phptherightway.com/) can help explain best practices.

Answer (score 0):

You can end the string and concatenate it with an expression. In this case, I use `$i++` which works like a counter. It returns the value of `$i` and then increments `$i` for the next iteration:

```
$i = 1;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['email']. " " . $row['name'] . "<input type='button' name='button" . $i++ . "' value= 'button' > <br />";

}
```

But 'row 1' doesn't always have to be the same row. Due to rows being added and removed you may get a different result, so 'button1' isn't a very good name. It would be better if you could use the name or id of the row. So if the person table has a numeric id as well, you could use that:

```
$query = mysql_query(" SELECT id, email, name FROM upload_jezici  ");
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    echo $row['email']. " " . $row['name'] . "<input type='button' name='button{$row['id']}' value= 'button' > <br />";

}
```

As you can see here, I didn't concat, but instead embedded the array variable in the string. This works similar to normal variables, except you *have* to put braces around the variable. Of course, you could still concatenate the value as in the first example.

Answer (score 0):

We use [] to create an array of the buttons 
I'm not in a live environment so I can't test it.

Accessing via $_POST:

```
$size = sizeof($_POST['button']);
for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++){echo $_POST['button'][$i];}
```

// Code

```
    include_once 'dbcon.php';
    $query = mysql_query(" SELECT email, name FROM upload_jezici  ");

    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
        echo $row['email']. " " . $row['name'] . "<input type='button' name='button[]' value= 'button' > <br />";
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

> $query = mysql_query(" SELECT id, email, name FROM upload_jezici  ");
>   while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
>       echo $row['email']. " " . $row['name'] . " 
> ";
>
> }

Yes, i've tried to increment with for loop, but no luck.. This is doing a job very well :)
Good idea. Thanks guys very much!